# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Message recipients data must be set.' in app/Mage.php:595

Tags: magento, exception, cron, magento-1.9

Suddenly I receiving this error with my cron which sends all mails from the webshop:

```
Cron error while executing core_email_queue_send_all:

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Message recipients data must be set.' in /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(98): Mage::throwException('Message recipie...')
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->_beforeSave()
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(248): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#4 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(196): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#6 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#7 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/shell/scheduler.php(377): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#12 /srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/srv/www/htdocs/virtual/webs/DOMAIN/htdocs/shell/scheduler.php(403): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#13 {main}
```

Does anybody know something about this issue?

Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your website, a transactional email has been allowed to be queued without a recipient specified. I suggest you take a tour in your database and find the `core_email_queue_recipients` table, and check for a row with an empty `recipient_email` value. You'll then keep the `message_id` found on the faulty row, and delete the corresponding entry in the `core_email_queue` table.

Comment: Same erro here but cant find any empty email recipient data